# Orthogonal unit vectors to 2 vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

My question is:

Find 2 unit vectors orthogonal to both vectors:
(1,-1,1) and (0,4,4)

So far, what I have done is constructing a line between the two vectors: 
(1,5,3).

What should i do next?

Comment: The usual "shortcut" in three-dimensions is called the cross-product of two vectors.  Are you familiar with it?

Answer (score 0):

Find $v=(a,b,c)$ such that 
$$v\cdot (1,-1,1)=a-b+c=0,\quad v\cdot (0,4,4)=4b+4c=0.$$
Then compute
$$||v||=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
And your vectors are
$$\pm \frac{1}{||v||}v.$$

Answer (score 0):

A vector $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $(1,-1,1)$ if and only if the inner product of the two is zero, i.e. 
$$x-y+z = 0\;.$$
Similarly, $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $(0,4,4)$ if and only if
$$4y+4z = 0\;.$$
Can you solve the following system of equations?
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}x-y+z &=&0 \\ 4y+4z &=& 0\end{array}\right.$$